# Pokein - How can i catch the offline message using Pokein library?

Tags: asp.net, comet, pokein

I've tried to do a chat application using [PokeIn](http://www.pokein.com). How can I do a offline messages when user is not in a chat and I'll try to send to him a message? How can I catch a unsent messages?

For example: SendToClient(CLIENT_ID_33, "Message");

User with ID 33 is not a chat and I want to save the message to a database? How can I catch this message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something you need to implement manually. You may call a server method from the client every time the user was able to get it.